# Complex SQL Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONDETAILS
(
    TransNo CHAR(15),
    Serial  INT,
    Project CHAR(3)
)
```

Dataset:

```
+-----------------+--------+---------+
|     TransNo     | Serial | Project |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000001 |      2 |     101 |
| A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |
| A00000000000003 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |
| A00000000000004 |      1 |     200 |
| A00000000000004 |      2 |     100 |
| A00000000000005 |      1 |     101 |
| A00000000000005 |      2 |     100 |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
```

I want to identify transactions those have same project sets.

Expected output:

```
+-----------------+--------+---------+---------+
|     TransNo     | Serial | Project | Flag    |
+-----------------+--------+---------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |      1 |     100 |     1   |
| A00000000000001 |      2 |     101 |     1   |
| A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |     1   |
| A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |     1   |
| A00000000000005 |      1 |     101 |     1   |
| A00000000000005 |      2 |     100 |     1   |
| A00000000000003 |      1 |     100 |     2   |
| A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |     2   |
| A00000000000004 |      1 |     200 |     2   |
| A00000000000004 |      2 |     100 |     2   |
+-----------------+--------+---------+---------+
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 and later.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:** Partially my objective would be achieved if I make following from input dataset.

```
+-----------------+---------+---------+
|     TransNo     | Project1| Project2|
+-----------------+---------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |     100 |     101 |
| A00000000000002 |     100 |     101 |
| A00000000000003 |     100 |     200 |
| A00000000000004 |     200 |     100 |
| A00000000000005 |     101 |     100 |
+-----------------+---------+---------+
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Data set

```
+-----------------+--------+---------+
|     TransNo     | Serial | Project |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000001 |      2 |     101 |
| A00000000000001 |      3 |     200 |
| A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |
| A00000000000003 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |
| A00000000000004 |      1 |     200 |
| A00000000000004 |      2 |     100 |
| A00000000000005 |      1 |     101 |
| A00000000000005 |      2 |     100 |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------------+--------+---------+---------+
|     TransNo     | Serial | Project | Flag    |
+-----------------+--------+---------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |      1 |     100 |     1   |
| A00000000000001 |      2 |     101 |     1   |
| A00000000000001 |      2 |     200 |     1   |
| A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |     2   |
| A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |     2   |
| A00000000000005 |      1 |     101 |     2   |
| A00000000000005 |      2 |     100 |     2   |
| A00000000000003 |      1 |     100 |     3   |
| A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |     3   |
| A00000000000004 |      1 |     200 |     3   |
| A00000000000004 |      2 |     100 |     3   |
+-----------------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: What is the logic for `Flag` column?

Comment: Flag is just identifying transactions with same project sets. Transaction those are committed between project 100 & 101 are flagged as 1 and those have 100 & 200 are flagged as 2. It could be anything int, char just an identification node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Concat(Min(Project)OVER(partition BY TransNo), Max(Project)OVER(partition BY TransNo)) AS inter
         FROM   TRANSACTIONDETAILS)
SELECT TransNo,
       Serial,
       Project,
       Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY inter) AS flag
FROM   cte
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf252/1)

**Update :** For partial result

```
SELECT TransNo,
       Max(CASE WHEN Serial = 1 THEN Project END) AS Project_1,
       Max(CASE WHEN Serial = 2 THEN Project END) AS Project_2
FROM   TRANSACTIONDETAILS
GROUP  BY TransNo
```

Comment: Would u please take a look to update 2. What if there exists 3 project in a transaction. By getting min and max con-cat for transaction A00000000000001  its resulting 100200 as inter. Is there any way to make it 100101200 ???

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505671/sql-concatenate-of-row-data-into-column)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #test_trans
    ([TransNo] varchar(15), [Serial] int, [Project] int)
;

INSERT INTO #test_trans
    ([TransNo], [Serial], [Project])
VALUES
    ('A00000000000001', 1, 100),
    ('A00000000000001', 2, 101),
    ('A00000000000001', 3, 200),
    ('A00000000000002', 1, 100),
    ('A00000000000002', 2, 101),
    ('A00000000000003', 1, 100),
    ('A00000000000003', 2, 200),
    ('A00000000000004', 1, 200),
    ('A00000000000004', 2, 100),
    ('A00000000000005', 1, 101),
    ('A00000000000005', 2, 100)
;

[![;WITH cte
     AS (select \[TransNo\],(
Select cast(ST1.\[Project\] as varchar(max))  AS \[text()\]
                From #test_trans ST1
                where st1.TransNo=st2.TransNo
                 For XML PATH ('')) as rn,Project,st2.Serial from #test_trans st2)
SELECT TransNo,
       Serial,
       Project,
       Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY rn) AS flag
FROM   cte][1]][1]
```

[image]