# Sql concatenate of row data into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Data set:

```
+-----------------+--------+---------+
|     TransNo     | Serial | Project |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000001 |      2 |     200 |
| A00000000000001 |      3 |     201 |
| A00000000000001 |      4 |     101 |
| A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |
| A00000000000003 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |
| A00000000000004 |      1 |     200 |
| A00000000000004 |      2 |     100 |
| A00000000000005 |      1 |     101 |
| A00000000000005 |      2 |     100 |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
```

I want to merge projects in a new column order by project & partition by transaction as following.
[Project will be merged by order ASC]

Output:

```
    +-----------------+--------+---------+------------------+
    |     TransNo     | Serial | Project | CProject         |
    +-----------------+--------+---------+------------------+
    | A00000000000001 |      1 |     100 |     100101200201 |
    | A00000000000001 |      2 |     200 |     100101200201 |
    | A00000000000001 |      3 |     201 |     100101200201 |
    | A00000000000001 |      4 |     101 |     100101200201 |
    | A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |     100101       |
    | A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |     100101       |
    | A00000000000005 |      1 |     101 |     100101       |
    | A00000000000005 |      2 |     100 |     100101       |
    | A00000000000003 |      1 |     100 |     100200       |
    | A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |     100200       |
    | A00000000000004 |      1 |     200 |     100200       |
    | A00000000000004 |      2 |     100 |     100200       |
    +-----------------+--------+---------+------------------+
```

**UPDATE 1:**

What to do if I want my output order by Serial instead of project.

```
    +-----------------+--------+---------+------------------+
    |     TransNo     | Serial | Project | CProject         |
    +-----------------+--------+---------+------------------+
    | A00000000000001 |      1 |     100 |     100200201101|
    | A00000000000001 |      2 |     200 |     100200201101|
    | A00000000000001 |      3 |     201 |     100200201101|
    | A00000000000001 |      4 |     101 |     100200201101|
    | A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |     100101       |
    | A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |     100101       |
    | A00000000000005 |      1 |     101 |     101100       |
    | A00000000000005 |      2 |     100 |     101100       |
    | A00000000000003 |      1 |     100 |     100200       |
    | A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |     100200       |
    | A00000000000004 |      1 |     200 |     200100       |
    | A00000000000004 |      2 |     100 |     200100       |
    +-----------------+--------+---------+------------------+
```

Comment: What is the significance of the numbers under "CProject"? I don't see an obvious pattern.

Comment: For transNo 'A00000000000001 ' CProject is the merge of all its projects by ascending order. See There exists 4 projects 100, 200, 201, 101 for this transaction and by merging them in ASC order it would be 100101200201

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    TransNo VARCHAR(20),
    Serial INT,
    Project INT
)

INSERT INTO @t (TransNo, Serial, Project)
VALUES
    ('A00000000000001', 1, 100),
    ('A00000000000001', 2, 200),
    ('A00000000000001', 3, 201),
    ('A00000000000001', 4, 101),
    ('A00000000000002', 1, 100),
    ('A00000000000002', 2, 101),
    ('A00000000000003', 1, 100),
    ('A00000000000003', 2, 200),
    ('A00000000000004', 1, 200),
    ('A00000000000004', 2, 100),
    ('A00000000000005', 1, 101),
    ('A00000000000005', 2, 100)

SELECT *, CProject = (
    SELECT DISTINCT [text()] = t2.Project
    FROM @t t2
    WHERE t2.TransNo = t1.TransNo
    ORDER BY t2.Project
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
FROM @t t1
```

output -

```
TransNo              Serial      Project     CProject
-------------------- ----------- ----------- --------------
A00000000000001      1           100         100101200201
A00000000000001      2           200         100101200201
A00000000000001      3           201         100101200201
A00000000000001      4           101         100101200201
A00000000000002      1           100         100101
A00000000000002      2           101         100101
A00000000000003      1           100         100200
A00000000000003      2           200         100200
A00000000000004      1           200         100200
A00000000000004      2           100         100200
A00000000000005      1           101         100101
A00000000000005      2           100         100101
```

with `[text()]` -

```
100101200201
```

without `[text()]` -

```
<Project>100</Project><Project>101</Project><Project>200</Project><Project>201</Project>
```

more details - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691102/String-Aggregation-in-the-World-of-SQL-Server

update -

```
SELECT *, CProject = (
    SELECT [text()] = t2.Project
    FROM (
        SELECT t2.Project, Serial = MIN(t2.Serial)
        FROM @t t2
        WHERE t2.TransNo = t1.TransNo
        GROUP BY t2.Project
    ) t2
    ORDER BY t2.Serial
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
FROM @t t1
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: Superb!!! But one tiny issue. Assuming for project 100, 200, 200, 101 would it be possible to return 100101200 ??

Comment: in this case need to add `DISTINCT`. please check the update

Comment: Hi Devart, what is `[text()]`, is it a function from xpath?

Comment: @Ogrish Man, `text()` function retrieve only the element values without nodes

Comment: @Smart003 you are welcome ;) also check this post - http://blog.devart.com/xml-xquery-perfomance-issues.html and may the Force be with you :))

Comment: I have tried to modify ur query to ORDER BY t2.Serial but its giving following error: 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified'

Comment: Hi @Devart thnx. Would u please take a look at [Sql Row Seperation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522483/sql-row-seperation)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.CProject
FROM t AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT SS.TransNo, (
            SELECT ' ' + US.Project     
            FROM t US
            WHERE US.TransNo = SS.TransNo
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) CProject
    FROM t SS
    GROUP BY SS.TransNo
    ORDER BY SS.Serial
) t2 ON t1.TransNo = t2.TransNo
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` does not exists on `SQL Server`

Comment: Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subquires, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: sorting in subqueries can lead to unexpected results