# Sql row separation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Schema:

```
Create Table
(
Transaction CHAR(18),
Serial INT,
Project CHAR(3),
Amount MONEY
CONSTRAINT [PK_TRANSACTION_SERIAL] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
Transaction ASC,
Serial ASC
)
)
```

Data set:

```
+-----------------+-------+---------+---------+
|     Transaction | Serial| Project | Amount  |
+-----------------+-------+---------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |     1 |     100 |     500 |
| A00000000000001 |     2 |     200 |    -200 |
| A00000000000001 |     3 |     200 |    -100 |
| A00000000000001 |     4 |     101 |    -200 |
| A00000000000002 |     1 |     100 |     100 |
| A00000000000002 |     2 |     101 |    -100 |
| A00000000000003 |     1 |     100 |     300 |
| A00000000000003 |     2 |     200 |    -300 |
| A00000000000004 |     1 |     200 |    -200 |
| A00000000000004 |     2 |     100 |     100 |
| A00000000000004 |     3 |     101 |     100 |
| A00000000000005 |     1 |     200 |     200 |
| A00000000000005 |     2 |     100 |    -300 |
| A00000000000005 |     3 |     101 |     100 |
+-----------------+-------+---------+---------+
```

For any transaction there will be either 1 positive balance against multiple negative balance or 1 negative against multiple positive. 
There will be no transaction as many positive amount against many negative amount.

Transactions with 1 positive and 1 negative amount is the best case scenario.

My target is to make all transactions 1 to 1 as following.

In first row at output amount for project 200 is merged as 2nd and 2rd row of dataset has same transaction ans same project.

Here the max ABS(amount) row for each transaction is being splitted into multiple rows according to the value of amount of other rows of that transaction.

Output:

```
+-----------------+---------+---------+
|     Transaction | Project | Amount  |
+-----------------+---------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |     100 |     300 |
| A00000000000001 |     200 |    -300 |
---------------------------------------
| A00000000000001 |     100 |     200 |
| A00000000000001 |     101 |    -200 |
---------------------------------------
| A00000000000002 |     100 |     100 |
| A00000000000002 |     101 |    -100 |
---------------------------------------
| A00000000000003 |     100 |     300 |
| A00000000000003 |     200 |    -300 |
---------------------------------------
| A00000000000004 |     200 |    -100 |
| A00000000000004 |     100 |     100 |
---------------------------------------
| A00000000000004 |     200 |    -100 |
| A00000000000004 |     101 |     100 |
---------------------------------------
| A00000000000005 |     200 |     200 |
| A00000000000005 |     100 |    -200 |
---------------------------------------
| A00000000000005 |     101 |     100 |
| A00000000000005 |     100 |    -100 |
+-----------------+---------+---------+
```

I am using SQL SERVER 2012 or higher.

Comment: It makes no sense how split value 500 for A...1 and Project 100 into 2 amounts? The rest really is a select sum(Amount) group by transaction, project from table.

Comment: For Transaction A...1 Project 100 has amount 500 and project 200 has amount -300(after summation of same project in same transaction) and project 101 has amount -200. So I want to relate Project 100 to 200 with amount 300 & -300 and Project 100 to 101 with amount 200 & -200.

Comment: is there ANY other column available such as ID (unique to each row)? How do you intend to ensure a row isn't included more than once?

Comment: See my updated dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Row separation approach but for getting this `1-1`  (negative and positive) value you can order your output.

you can order based on transaction and then absolute value of your amount like -

`select * 
    from <your_table_name> 
   order by Transaction, abs(Amount)`

Comment: With your approach order by transaction and ABS(Amount) and taking the max(Amount) for each transaction I may find which row I need to split in multiple. But How I am going to split it?